# Hightlighting records on adding / update in xamdatagrid

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I am using a XamDatagrid,

I using a BindingList to populate the grid.

Any idea on how to highlight a record when its is added / updated on backgroud. Trying to develop a app that would keep listening to data being published and would display them on UI

Answer (score 0):

the most easy way would be to add a property to your dataitem eg. IsUpdated, IsAdded and then create a cellstyle trigger listen to these properties.

Answer (score 0):

Early last year I posted a sample on the Infragistics forums that highlights cells as the data changes:
http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/p/50428/266192.aspx#266192